# MMB Breaks in from orthographic view to 3d view

Tags: modeling

When am in an orthographic view either front or side and 
try to rotate with the MMB it breaks in to 3d view port. The camera doesn’t show on the model unless I zoom out and zoom in to see the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using Blender 2.8. In 2.8, pressing 1, 3, and 7, locks you view to X, Y, and Z axis, as well as setting your view to orthographic. Breaking this view disables orthographic mode. If you wish to enable it manually, and view other angles, press 5 on the numpad.